# libvirt: "Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend"

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm trying to set up a virtual NAT network device without DHCP for libvirt on an Arch Linux host.

What I have tried:

```
# virsh net-define network.xml 
Network default defined from network.xml
```

[`network.xml`]:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <bridge name="maas0" />
  <forward mode="nat" />
  <ip address="10.137.0.1" netmask="255.255.255.0" />
</network>
```

My laptop outputs the following on start-up:

```
# virsh net-start default
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error: Failed to initialize a valid firewall backend
```

All other threads concerning this topic are talking about upgrading software -- I'm using the most current versions:

```
$ pacman -Q ebtables dnsmasq libvirt iptables
ebtables 2.0.10_4-5
dnsmasq 2.75-1
libvirt 1.3.3-1
iptables 1.4.21-3
```

What could be the reason for that `internal error` and what can I do against?

Answer (score 54):

Installing `ebtables` and `dnsmasq` seems to fix the problem. Don't forget to restart the `libvirtd` service.

The commands:

```
sudo pacman -Syu ebtables dnsmasq
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```

NOTE: do not forget to close and re-open your `virt-manager` GUI (if you're using one).

**EDIT:** The original answer suggested also installing `firewalld`. This doesn't seem to be necessary for many users, and may add an additional unwanted firewall to your system. However if you want to try it, you can add the following commands as well:

```
sudo pacman -Syu firewalld
sudo systemctl start firewalld
sudo systemctl enable firewalld
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd
```

Comment: There's no need to install `firewalld`, it's also [not listed on ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/libvirt#Server), it's just necessary to start `ebtables` and `dnsmasq`, with `libvirtd`/`virtlogd` afterwards.

Comment: I want to emphasize, **restart libvirtd**, after installing `ebtables` and `dnsmasq`

Comment: I confirm there's no need to install `firewalld`, as noted by @pepper_chico (comment) and [Stuart P. Bentley](https://superuser.com/a/1360773/1038080) (other answer).

Comment: installing `ebtables` for me meant replacing `iptables` with `iptables-nft` as their packages conflicted. I had nothing configured in `iptables` and the change seems to have not broken anything.

Answer (score 11):

This is the error that comes up if libvirtd was *started* without `ebtables` and/or `dnsmasq` installed. If you've got them installed and you're still having this issue, you probably need to restart the `libvirtd` service:

```
sudo systemctl restart libvirtd.service
```

---

Credit to [the](https://superuser.com/questions/1063240/libvirt-failed-to-initialize-a-valid-firewall-backend#comment1893457_1090815) [comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1063240/libvirt-failed-to-initialize-a-valid-firewall-backend#comment2028302_1090815) on the other answer to this question for illuminating this. I'm submitting it as a new and separate answer to the original question because installing and starting `firewalld` to solve the original problem is liable to **cause new problems**: once the firewall daemon is running, most of the services you'll want within your virtual machine, **including DHCP, will be blocked by default**, meaning that your VMs will not be able to reach the network on initialization.

I lost over an hour of my life trying to track down this problem, and tracing it to *a firewall I had just enabled* was one of the dumbest sources of a bug that I've ever run into. Don't let it take any time from *yours*.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not able yet to add an additional comment to the most upvoted answer, I had to add this solution as a new answer instead.

In some cases, users might not want to replace `iptables` with `iptables-nft` as it might break existing rules.

The legacy `iptables` package contains `ebtables-nft` which is a symlink to `xtables-nft-multi`.

You can check this using file:

```
$ file $(which ebtables-nft)
/usr/bin/iptables: symbolic link to xtables-nft-multi
```

A simple solution is to create the **missing** symlinks so `libvirt/virt-manager` can find it without touching existing packages on your system.

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/xtables-nft-multi /usr/bin/ebtables
$ ln -s /usr/bin/xtables-nft-multi /usr/bin/ebtables-save
$ ln -s /usr/bin/xtables-nft-multi /usr/bin/ebtables-restore
```

Restart the `libvirt` daemons/sockets (whatever you use) afterwards and the networks should start without the **firewall backend** error.